# to convert 'for ~in' statement in python

Tags: python, for-loop

I want to add the columns in each column and code them in the same pattern.
But I want to convert it to a for statement because the code is lengthened, but I do not know.

```
df4 = df2.loc[:,['no','date','code','code2','code3','code4','code5','code6','code7'.....]]

df4.loc[df2['code'] == 'A1346A', 'name'] = 0 
df4.loc[df2['code'] == 'A1302A', 'name'] = 0 
df4.loc[df2['code'] == 'A0000A', 'name'] = 1 
df4.loc[df2['code'] == 'A0533A', 'name'] = 1 
df4.loc[df2['code'] == 'A0533A', 'name'] = 2 
df4.loc[df2['code'] == 'A0533A', 'name'] = 2 
df4.loc[df2['code'] == 'A1516A', 'name'] = 2 
df4.loc[df2['code'] == 'A1483A', 'name'] = 3
df4.loc[df2['code'] == 'A1484A', 'name'] = 3


df4.loc[df2['code2'] == 'A1346A', 'name2'] = 0 
df4.loc[df2['code2'] == 'A1302A', 'name2'] = 0 
df4.loc[df2['code2'] == 'A0000A', 'name2'] = 1 
df4.loc[df2['code2'] == 'A0533A', 'name2'] = 1 
df4.loc[df2['code2'] == 'A0533A', 'name2'] = 2 
df4.loc[df2['code2'] == 'A0533A', 'name2'] = 2 
df4.loc[df2['code2'] == 'A1516A', 'name2'] = 2 
df4.loc[df2['code2'] == 'A1483A', 'name2'] = 3
df4.loc[df2['code2'] == 'A1484A', 'name2'] = 3



df4.loc[df2['code3'] == 'A1346A', 'name3'] = 0 
df4.loc[df2['code3'] == 'A1302A', 'name3'] = 0 
df4.loc[df2['code3'] == 'A0000A', 'name3'] = 1 
df4.loc[df2['code3'] == 'A0533A', 'name3'] = 1 
df4.loc[df2['code3'] == 'A0533A', 'name3'] = 2 
df4.loc[df2['code3'] == 'A0533A', 'name3'] = 2 
df4.loc[df2['code3'] == 'A1516A', 'name3'] = 2 
df4.loc[df2['code3'] == 'A1483A', 'name3'] = 3
df4.loc[df2['code3'] == 'A1484A', 'name3'] = 3
```

Comment: FYI -- the "snippet" functionality is only for code that can run in a browser. Use the `{}` button (or four-space indents, or triple-backticks) to syntax-highlight code in other languages.

Comment: What you trying to do here and why are you setting certain things more than once to different values (eg: `A0533A` gets set to 1, then 2, then 2 again...?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for suffix in ['', '1', '2']:
    df4.loc[df2['code' + suffix] == 'A1346A', 'name' + suffix] = 0
    ...
    df4.loc[df2['code' + suffix] == 'A1484A', 'name' + suffix] = 3
```

Comment: I've been looking for.I am thankful to you for your help.